# Assigning a Template to a Vue Class Component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

How does one assign a template to a Vue class component directly? In the example below, I can render the subcomponent as a node, but never renders the template. I've tried to assign the template many different ways to get it to render, but nothing seems to work:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>This should render one, two, three below twice.</p>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item">
      {{ item }}
      <Subcomponent :item="item" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

  @Component({ template:`<span>{{item}}</span>` })
  class Subcomponent extends Vue {
    template = `<span>{{ item }}</span>`
    @Prop({required: true})
    item: string
  }

  @Component({ components: { Subcomponent } })
  export default class Test extends Vue {
    items = ['one', 'two', 'three']
  }
</script>
```

Note I'm also having the same issue if I use a Vue.component directly:

```
Vue.component('Subcomponent', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: '<span>{{item}}</span>'
})
```

Comment: Your Subcomponent isn't rendering anything at all? `{item}` should definitely be `{{ item }}` in your Subcomponent's template

Comment: It shows up as a node, but does not render anything. I don't think I'm assigning the template properly, and I've updated the question title to reflect that.

Comment: What do you mean by `shows up as a node, but does not render anything`? Using `Vue.component` directly, which has nothing to do with TS works like a charm in a regular app ([see here](https://jsfiddle.net/fwuwta5p/)). You're using `.vue` files, right? I have never declared multiple components into a single file - are you sure that's reasonable and not causing problems?

Comment: You see a DOM node is created for each Subcomponent (it even renders in Vue devtools as Subcomponent) but there's nothing inside the DOM node (no template has rendered.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code is ok.
Check that you are using fresh versions of packages and your configs.

I've just created new project with

`vue init ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript my-project`

After integrating your code to newly created project, I've realized that all is working correctly:

```
<div><p>This should render one, two, three below twice.</p> <div>
      one
      <span>one</span></div><div>
      two
      <span>two</span></div><div>
      three
      <span>three</span></div></div>
```